# Magnetic vector potential problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I'm having a quite hard time understanding an exercise from Demarest on the magnetic vector potential that should be rather simple.

The question is:

> [image]

The answer to part a) is:

> [image]

Sorry if the question is rather short, but what I fail to understand is how the integral is interpreted and solved in the solution. Somewhat we get the result $$\int_{l/2}^{-l/2}{dz} = 1$$ which, unless I'm misinterpreting something, is wrong...
If anyone could help I'd be glad.
Also, I wonder how $â_z$ is introduced in the integral. Should $dl'$ be a vector? I also fail to understand why the upper bound is -l/2 and not l/2...

Perhaps someone has a better way of solving it or could explain me the actual solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is not correct, I'm guessing the author made a typo. As you might have guessed:
$$\int_{-l/2}^{l/2}{dz}=l$$
Not 1. So $dl$ is a vector pointing along the length of the filament (or more generally, the direction of the current). Since the filament is oriented in the z direction, you can replace it with $\hat{a}_z dz$. Usually the integration is from $-l/2$ to $l/2$. If you integrate the other way,  the sign would cancel out because $d\vec{l} = -\hat{a}_z dz$ because the current is oriented in the positive z direction.

In conclusion, the result should be:

$$\vec{A}=\hat{a}_z \frac{\mu I_0 l}{4 \pi r}$$

Comment: Indeed after a night of sleep it didn't make sense at all to me either. I just wanted to be sure there was not some sort of "trick" along that. Thanks a lot.